# How to reply to google plus post using PHP google client

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-client

I want to post a comment to google plus post using php google client but I didn't find any documentation for how to do this. Please point me on the right path.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? The docs only list [`get` and `list`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/comments) as possible REST methods.

Comment: I just made a system using google plus. but right now it is impossible to post in google plus. here check the methods at the bottom: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities

Answer (score 1):

The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) is read only.  You can select from it only you can not use it to post to the [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/) Social media website.

The closes you can come to is [Google+ share](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) which basicly just gives you a share button users can use.

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
```